# SQLException при работе с БД

Tags: java, sql, исключения

Есть такие методы:

```
package com.LTP.Controllers;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import com.LTP.main.User;

public class DBController {

    private static Connection c;
    private static Statement s;

    public static void init(String url, String login, String password) {
        try {
            c = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
            s = c.createStatement();
        }catch(SQLException e) {ExceptionType.CANNOTCONNECT.throwException();}
    }

    public static ResultSet Run(String query) {
        ResultSet result = null;

        try {
            result = s.executeQuery(query);
        }catch(SQLException e)        {ExceptionType.CANNOTCONNECT.throwException();}

        return result;
    }

}
```

При запуске кода таким образом:

```
DBController.Run("INSERT INTO users (login, password) VALUES ('" + login.getText() + "', '" + password.getText() + "')");
```

где login - JTextField, password - JPasswordField

Вылетает такая ошибка:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.checkForDml(StatementImpl.java:469)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1338)
at com.LTP.Controllers.DBController.Run(DBController.java:27)
at com.LTP.main.RegistrationPanel$2.actionPerformed(RegistrationPanel.java:59)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Используйте `executeUpdate` вместо `executeQuery`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод executeQuery необходим для запросов, результатом которых является один единственный набор значений, таких как запросов SELECT.

Метод executeUpdate используется для выполнения операторов INSERT, UPDATE или DELETE, например, CREATE TABLE и DROP TABLE. Результатом оператора INSERT, UPDATE, или DELETE является модификация одной или более колонок в нуле или более строках таблицы. Метод executeUpdate возвращает целое число, показывающее, сколько строк было модифицировано.